# Cannot insert the value null error but value isn't actually null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an error that *seems* simple to resolve, but I have not been able to do so.  When I run a statement to insert one record into a table I receive the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission', table 'TableA'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Simple, right?  I am trying to insert null into a column that doesn't allow it.  However in the INSERT statement *I am explicitly inserting a value for that column*.  Nothing fancy, no dynamic SQL, no subqueries or anything like that.  I have a simple statement with every value enumerated. This is failing with the above error

`TableA` consists of 81 columns.  It is the configuration table for a large web application.  The column does not allow nulls.  The column data type is a bit (a TRUE/FALSE flag for the application).  I cannot alter the design of the table.

IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission Definition:

```
+------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
|            COLUMN_NAME             | DATA_TYPE | TYPE_NAME | PRECISION | LENGTH | SCALE | RADIX | NULLABLE | REMARKS | COLUMN_DEF | SQL_DATA_TYPE | SQL_DATETIME_SUB | CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH | ORDINAL_POSITION | IS_NULLABLE | SS_DATA_TYPE |
+------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
| IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission |        -7 | bit       |         1 |      1 | NULL  | NULL  |        0 | NULL    | ((0))      |            -7 | NULL             | NULL              |               63 | NO          |           50 |
+------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+---------+------------+---------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

I am passing in `0` for `IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission`, I also tried `'0'`.  Both result in the same error.

I haven't found much online so far other than people trying to add values in columns that are set as an identity, but that scenario is not relevant here as the column I am trying to add a value to is a simple 0/1 flag, not an identity.

I would be happy to provide more information if required.  The actual insert statement is long (81 columns that I am explicitly assigning values to).

### Update

Here is the table (TableA) definition:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
|                   Column_name                   |   Type   | Computed | Length | Prec  | Scale | Nullable | TrimTrailingBlanks | FixedLenNullInSource |          Collation           |
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| BUSNS_UNIT_ID                                   | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| BUSNS_UNIT_NM                                   | nvarchar | no       |     40 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| ALLOW_RPG_EDIT_FLAG                             | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| FISCAL_YR_START_MTH                             | tinyint  | no       |      1 |     3 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| INPUT_FORM_EXCEL_FLAG                           | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| SHOW_COMPOSITE_CALCULATION_TYPE                 | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DEFAULT_COMPOSITE_CALCULATION_TYPE              | nvarchar | no       |    200 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| MAP_ALL_DEPT_FLAG                               | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| COMPST_MIN_DLRS_TO_RUN                          | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ACCT_DATA_TYP                                   | varchar  | no       |     10 |       |       | yes      | no                 | yes                  | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT                       | varchar  | no       |     10 |       |       | yes      | no                 | yes                  | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| FORM_READONLY_FLAG                              | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| CMPST_RUN_MTHS                                  | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| CMPST_RUN_YRS                                   | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DISPLAY_LCL_ACCT_NBR                            | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| csv_delimiter                                   | varchar  | no       |      2 |       |       | no       | no                 | no                   | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| SHOW_PLANS                                      | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| INPUT_FORM_TEMPLATE_NAME                        | nvarchar | no       |    300 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| COMPST_RUN_REVIEWSTATUS_DEFAULT                 | tinyint  | no       |      1 |     3 |     0 | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AllowDuplicateAccountData                       | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| FILE_IMPORT_SCHEMA                              | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ALLOW_DELETE_COMPOSITE                          | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| Disable_Multiple_StarMap                        | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AllowMasterAccountMap                           | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowCompositesToVendors                         | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AllowCompositeClosedSnapShot                    | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| SubmissionFrequencyID                           | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AutoRecalculate                                 | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowDealerCodeAlternate                         | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowSubDealerIndicator                          | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowDealerType                                  | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| OnlineBusinessPlan                              | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowInactiveItemsAdvancedCriteria               | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| HonorRollType                                   | nvarchar | no       |    200 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| ShowInactiveDealersDataSubmission               | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AllowFinancialDataSuppression                   | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AllowDataSubmissionComments                     | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| RejectMatchingSubmissions                       | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| HonorRollAccuracyPoint                          | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| HonorRollNonSubmissionPoint                     | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DisableInputFormAccountHighlight                | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DisableInputFormAuditComments                   | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableSubDealers                                | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowCompositesInDealerProfile                   | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableCarryForwardAuditRemark                   | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableInputFormInlineEvents                     | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| PreventOverMap                                  | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DefaultAdhocReportVariablesTab                  | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalFormula                           | nvarchar | no       |     -1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| InvestmentGuideFormula                          | nvarchar | no       |     -1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| DualDealerAppointmentMonthCutoff                | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalSubmissionsStartMonth             | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalSubmissionsEndMonth               | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalSuccessfulSubmissionsMinimum      | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalStartMonth                        | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalEndMonth                          | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkingCapitalActivationMonthCutoff             | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AdhocShowAllUserReports                         | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AuditResultsLinkStatus                          | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ShowHistoricCompositesEntitySearch              | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| WorkSheetFullScreenMode                         | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| OnlineBusinessForecast                          | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission              | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| SpecialCarryForward                             | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DmsFileTransferFormat                           | nvarchar | no       |     -1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| SiteLogo                                        | varchar  | no       |     -1 |       |       | yes      | no                 | yes                  | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| SubmissionPointsThreshold                       | int      | no       |      4 |    10 |     0 | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableCompositeAverageByDepartment              | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ViewPreviousSubmission                          | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| HideAuditResultZeroValues                       | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| KeepReleasedFileImportData                      | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ArlAccountNumberParse                           | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| ConvertForecastRoles                            | nvarchar | no       |     -1 |       |       | yes      | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS |
| ArlEnableUndo                                   | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| UnhideAuditResultSummaryAccountZeroValues       | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| AlwaysShowAuditResultSummaryAccountCarryForward | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| CompositeAverageSummaryAccounts                 | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| DynamicPortfolio                                | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableAllocationAccounts                        | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableTermsAndConditions                        | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
| EnableSimultaneousAudit                         | bit      | no       |      1 |       |       | no       | (n/a)              | (n/a)                | NULL                         |
+-------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------+-------+-------+----------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+
```

And here is the full INSERT statement that generates the error:

```
INSERT INTO TableA SELECT
'14' AS BUSNS_UNIT_ID,
'Global' AS  BUSNS_UNIT_NM,
'0' AS  ALLOW_RPG_EDIT_FLAG,
'1' AS  FISCAL_YR_START_MTH,
'1' AS  INPUT_FORM_EXCEL_FLAG,
'0' AS  SHOW_COMPOSITE_CALCULATION_TYPE,
'ANNUALIZATION' AS  DEFAULT_COMPOSITE_CALCULATION_TYPE,
'0' AS  MAP_ALL_DEPT_FLAG,
'3' AS  COMPST_MIN_DLRS_TO_RUN,
'Cumulative' AS  ACCT_DATA_TYP,
'Period' AS  DECIMAL_SEPARATOR_DEFAULT,
'0' AS  FORM_READONLY_FLAG,
'25' AS  CMPST_RUN_MTHS,
'3' AS  CMPST_RUN_YRS,
'1' AS  DISPLAY_LCL_ACCT_NBR,
',' AS  csv_delimiter,
'0' AS  SHOW_PLANS,
NULL AS  INPUT_FORM_TEMPLATE_NAME,
'4' AS  COMPST_RUN_REVIEWSTATUS_DEFAULT,
'0' AS  AllowDuplicateAccountData,
'0' AS  FILE_IMPORT_SCHEMA,
'1' AS  ALLOW_DELETE_COMPOSITE,
'0' AS  Disable_Multiple_StarMap,
'0' AS  AllowMasterAccountMap,
'1' AS  ShowCompositesToVendors,
'0' AS  AllowCompositeClosedSnapShot,
'1' AS  SubmissionFrequencyID,
'0' AS  AutoRecalculate,
'0' AS  ShowDealerCodeAlternate,
'0' AS  ShowSubDealerIndicator,
'0' AS  ShowDealerType,
'0' AS  OnlineBusinessPlan,
'1' AS  ShowInactiveItemsAdvancedCriteria,
'SUBMISSION' AS  HonorRollType,
'0' AS  ShowInactiveDealersDataSubmission,
'0' AS  AllowFinancialDataSuppression,
'1' AS  AllowDataSubmissionComments,
'1' AS  RejectMatchingSubmissions,
'0' AS  HonorRollAccuracyPoint,
'0' AS  HonorRollNonSubmissionPoint,
'0' AS  DisableInputFormAccountHighlight,
'0' AS  DisableInputFormAuditComments,
'0' AS  EnableSubDealers,
'1' AS  ShowCompositesInDealerProfile,
'0' AS  EnableCarryForwardAuditRemark,
'0' AS  EnableInputFormInlineEvents,
'0' AS  PreventOverMap,
'0' AS  DefaultAdhocReportVariablesTab,
'' AS  WorkingCapitalFormula,
'' AS  InvestmentGuideFormula,
'0' AS  DualDealerAppointmentMonthCutoff,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalSubmissionsStartMonth,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalSubmissionsEndMonth,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalSuccessfulSubmissionsMinimum,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalStartMonth,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalEndMonth,
'0' AS  WorkingCapitalActivationMonthCutoff,
'0' AS  AdhocShowAllUserReports,
'0' AS  AuditResultsLinkStatus,
'0' AS  ShowHistoricCompositesEntitySearch,
'0' AS  WorkSheetFullScreenMode,
'0' AS  SpecialCarryForward,
NULL AS  DmsFileTransferFormat,
NULL AS  SiteLogo,
'0' AS  SubmissionPointsThreshold,
'0' AS  EnableCompositeAverageByDepartment,
'1' AS  ViewPreviousSubmission,
'0' AS  HideAuditResultZeroValues,
'1' AS  KeepReleasedFileImportData,
'0' AS  ArlAccountNumberParse,
NULL AS  ConvertForecastRoles,
'0' AS  ArlEnableUndo,
'0' AS  UnhideAuditResultSummaryAccountZeroValues,
'0' AS  AlwaysShowAuditResultSummaryAccountCarryForward,
'0' AS  CompositeAverageSummaryAccounts,
'0' AS  OnlineBusinessForecast,
'0' AS  IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission,
'0' AS  DynamicPortfolio,
'0' AS  EnableAllocationAccounts,
'0' AS  EnableTermsAndConditions,
'0' AS  EnableSimultaneousAudit
```

The INSERT statement is generated after configuring things in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: The actual insert statement may very well be relevant, as may the full table definition. If your column order accidentally doesn't precisely match the value order, for instance, you may be attempting to insert `NULL` into another column than you intend.

Comment: Can you show the `insert` statement? and the code that generates the `SQL`?

Comment: Are there any **triggers** on that table?

Comment: Are you explicitly mentioning Column name in your insert something like `INSERT INTO (Column_Name) VALUES (1)`... Since it is a bit column insert int `1` or `0`.

Comment: There are no triggers on the table.  I will update to include insert statement as well as table definition.  The insert statement is made in Excel as a concatenation of the 81 rows of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is the ordering of your columns in your Excel spreadsheet doesn't match the column order of your TableA. Your column 'IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission' is at the 63rd position in your TableA table definition, but it's at the 77th position in your spreadsheet.

If you look up position 63 in your spreadsheet you'll find DmsFileTransferFormat, which in your case has value NULL. I'm guessing this is the source of your error.

Either arrange the order of the columns in your spreadsheet to match the order of the columns in TableA or explicitly specify the columns in your INSERT statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableA (BUSNS_UNIT_ID, BUSNS_UNIT_NM, ALLOW_RPG_EDIT_FLAG, etc.) SELECT
'14' AS BUSNS_UNIT_ID,
'Global' AS  BUSNS_UNIT_NM,
'0' AS  ALLOW_RPG_EDIT_FLAG,
etc
```

Comment: This is good to know, in fact I'm slightly embarrassed I didn't think of this.  For whatever reason I assumed that aliasing the columns as their appropriate column name would've removed ambiguity but that is clearly not the case.  Thank you kindly for your help!

Comment: I have learned this the hard way as well, glad I could help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The columns in your insert statement are out of sync with the columns in the table. The fact that you name the columns in the `select` part of your `insert` statement will not cause the insert to *align* (for lack of a better word) the columns to the table definition.

When doing an insert like the one you do here, the columns in the select statement must be in the correct order with regards to the table you are inserting to. Checking your table definition and comparing to the select, we have on row 63 in the table:

```
| IsFutureDateAllowForDataSubmission              |
```

while in the select we have:

```
NULL AS  DmsFileTransferFormat
```

So you **are** trying to insert `null` into the column. To fix the problem you can either rearrange the columns in the `select` statement so that they are in the same order as in the table definition, or you can add a column order before the `select`:

```
insert into TableA  (BUSNS_UNIT_ID, ...)
    select ...
```

and then make sure that you list the column names within the parentheses in the same order as they appear in the subsequent `select`.